# How MS Teams auto logs into Azure AD

Tags: electron, azure-active-directory, adal, microsoft-teams

I tried few plugins to implement [Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-whatis) auto-login functionality to an [Electron app](https://electronjs.org/), but each of them had login issues [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718222/microsoft-azure-login-fails-in-electron-app) if I choose **file system URL(file:///)**.

This is because Electron apps run on file system URLs and Azure AD doesn't accepts a file system URL.

As much as I know, [MS Teams](https://teams.microsoft.com/downloads) is build on Electron. 
How have they achieved it? 
Do I need to run a local server like [electron-with-express](https://github.com/frankhale/electron-with-express)?

Comment: The way we are doing it is by calling [ADAL libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries) directly. There may be an npm module available, I'm checking if it's been released.